# Radio buttons in the form, if one checked then unchecked the others?

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I have three different group of radio buttons in my form. If I click on the radio button I don't see attribute checked set to true. I'm wondering what is the best way to handle this in JQuery/JavaScript? Here is example:

```js
$("input[type=radio]").on('click', function() {
  var secondClick = true;
  $(this).change(function() {
    secondClick = false;
  });
  $(this).click(function() {
    if (secondClick) {
      $(this).prop("checked", false);
    }
    secondClick = true;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" method="POST" action="#">
  <div class="formItem">
    <label for="evaluation">Evaluation</label>
    <input type="radio" name="frm_eval" id="frm_eval1" value="0" />Yes
    <input type="radio" name="frm_eval" id="frm_eval2" value="1" />No
  </div>
  <div class="formItem">
    <label for="conditions">Conditions</label>
    <input type="radio" name="frm_cond" id="frm_cond1" value="0" />Good
    <input type="radio" name="frmhs_cond" id="frm_cond2" value="1" />Fair
    <input type="radio" name="frm_cond" id="frm_cond3" value="2" />Poor
  </div>
  <div class="formItem">
    <label for="responses">Responses</label>
    <input type="radio" name="frm_res" id="frm_res1" value="0" />Good
    <input type="radio" name="frm_res" id="frm_res2" value="1" />Fair
    <input type="radio" name="frm_res" id="frm_res3" value="2" />Poor
  </div>
</form>
```

Function above did not change/set the attribute checked=true on the element that I clicked. I would like to see selected element with an attribute checked true and all other check boxes to be set to false.

Comment: In second group you have different name `frmhs_cond` instead of `frm_cond`

Answer (score 0):

Your second input in conditions was named frmhs_cond instead of frm_cond

```html
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" method="POST" action="#">
            <div class="formItem">
                <label for="evaluation">Evaluation</label>
                <input type="radio" name="frm_eval" id="frm_eval1" value="0" />Yes
                <input type="radio" name="frm_eval" id="frm_eval2" value="1" />No
            </div>
            <div class="formItem">
                <label for="conditions">Conditions</label>
                <input type="radio" name="frm_cond" id="frm_cond1" value="0" />Good
                <input type="radio" name="frm_cond" id="frm_cond2" value="1" />Fair
                <input type="radio" name="frm_cond" id="frm_cond3" value="2" />Poor
            </div>
            <div class="formItem">
                <label for="responses">Responses</label>
                <input type="radio" name="frm_res" id="frm_res1" value="0" />Good
                <input type="radio" name="frm_res" id="frm_res2" value="1" />Fair
                <input type="radio" name="frm_res" id="frm_res3" value="2" />Poor
            </div>
         </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var radioInputs = $("#myForm input[type=radio]")
radioInputs.on('change',function() {
  var $this = $(this)
  
  if ($this.is(':checked')) {
    radioInputs.not($this).removeAttr('checked')
  }
})
```